# how to use Linq count with group by in C#

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

i have a datatable in which look like this 
[image: datatable input]  
basically i want it to be group by column featurename(distinct) in which it should sum in effort and complete column 
 
specify all the featureid,featurename comma seprated
count of the featureid
assigned to comman seprated 
now i want datatable to be look like this 
[image]

 don't know how to use the count
code

```
var result5= dtTaskandBugs.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x["Functional Area"])
                               .Select(item => new
                               {
                                   FunctionalArea = item.Key,

                                   Completedsum = item.Sum(y => Convert.ToDecimal(y["Completed"])),
                                   effortsum = item.Sum(z => Convert.ToDecimal(z["effort"])),
                                   storyids = string.Join(",", item.Select(a => a["Storyid"]).Distinct()),
                                   storiesename= string.Join(",", item.Select(b => b["StoryName"]).Distinct()),
                                   Featureid = string.Join(",", item.Select(c => c["Featureid"]).Distinct()),
                                   Featurename= string.Join(",", item.Select(d => d["FeatureName"]).Distinct()),

                               });
```

Comment: Share some code block of data structure. No one will write whole code for you. SO is not code development platform. What did you do to achieve this and what error you got? Also, please read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn about [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: added the code @GaurangDave don't know how to use the count

Answer (score 3):

With `Count()` you will get count of grouped value.
Try with `Linq` like this:

```
from s in dtTaskandBugs.AsEnumerable()
                        group s by s.Field<string>("Functional Area")
                            into grp
                            orderby grp.Key
                            select new { 
                                   FunctionalArea = grp.Key,
                                   Completedsum = grp.Sum(y => Convert.ToDecimal(y["Completed"])),
                                   effortsum = grp.Sum(z => Convert.ToDecimal(z["effort"])),
                                   storyids = string.Join(",", grp.Select(a => a["Storyid"]).Distinct()),
                                   storiesename= string.Join(",", grp.Select(b => b["StoryName"]).Distinct()),
                                   Featureid = string.Join(",", grp.Select(c => c["Featureid"]).Distinct()),
                                   Featurename= string.Join(",", grp.Select(d => d["FeatureName"]).Distinct()),
                                   Count = grp.Count()          // <----------------
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write `item.count()` and you will get count of grouped values,

Comment: i need count of featureid only

Comment: Then you should use sum of feature I'd instead of group count. `FeatureidCount =  item.Sum(c => c["Featureid"])`